# Stop windows resuming from hibernation to install automatic updates

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I always hibernate my work (Windows 7, x64) laptop when leaving for the night. Sometimes when I come in again in the morning, the laptop is powered up and there's a message telling me that new updates have been installed. (I've changed the registry so automatic updates don't force a reboot.)

I'm happy to have Windows apply updates automatically, but I don't want it to resume from hibernation to do so. How can I stop this behaviour so I'm not wasting electricity?

Comment: You may be able to use the Device Manager and disable the ability to of your network adapters to wake the system. Another alternative would be to physically unplug or disconnect it from the LAN/internet before you leave each night.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to stop Windows from resuming from hibernation to install updates, see the answers to this question: [Windows Update waking machine from hibernation](https://superuser.com/questions/357033/windows-update-waking-machine-from-hibernation)