# How to prevent Windows 10 waking from sleep when traveling in bag?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, windows-task-scheduler

I am not turning laptop off, but rather putting into hibernation, as it starts much faster and I can continue working without starting all apps again.

It was working long time from Windows XP to Windows 8.1.

However now (after upgrade to Windows 10), when I just take my laptop out of the bag after a travel, it was quite hot. I've realized that it is turned on.

In the event log I have found that it was installing updates and before that there was the following log:

> The system has returned from a low power state.
>
> Sleep Time: ‎2015‎-‎08‎-‎16T12:55:18.180075900Z Wake Time:
>   ‎2015‎-‎08‎-‎16T12:55:17.852758500Z
>
> Wake Source: Unknown, but possibily due to timer - Windows will
>   execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot'
>   scheduled task that requested waking the computer.

When I located the task above in the task scheduler, it has trigger in that time, however the "last run time" is day before. So I do not know what to believe "last run time" or the wake source from the event above?

How to find out what is waking the computer from the hibernation (it is possible?) and how to prevent it?

Comment: i found a page that forces windows to not change the reboot http://superuser.com/questions/973009/conclusively-stop-wake-timers-from-waking-windows-10-desktop

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This has worked for me so far. Go to:

Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings

Click "Change advanced power settings"

Go to "Sleep->Allow wake timers" and change the setting to Disable.

[image: power options screenshot 1]

**UPDATE:** As Erik pointed out, there can be two options:

[image: power options screenshot 2 with 2 options]

Disable them both.

**UPDATE #2:**

In addition to wake timers, peripheral devices can also wake your computer. See Rosdi's answer for network interfaces. It reminded me of something I had to change recently as my computer was waking again when peripherals were attached. First I disconnected the mouse, but it turned out to be the keyboard.

Open the Device Manager and expand Keyboards - or whatever your problematic device category is - and find the suspect, e.g. "HID Keyboard Device". Right-click that and select Properties, then go to the Power Management tab and uncheck "Allow this device to wake the computer".

[image: Device properties Power Management tab]

Comment: Didn't work for me, that was already disabled, and Windows update woke up my PC anyway

Comment: Use "powercfg -waketimers" to check for presence of any other wake timers. Some versions of Spotify and TeamViewer are reported to create wake timers as well. However, I also have issue of Windows 10 ignoring disabled wake timers.

Comment: For anyone reading this, Spotify fixed the bug that made it create wake timers a few weeks ago.

Comment: Actually, in this instance, you only need to disable "On battery", as if your laptop is plugged in it isn't in your bag.

Comment: For the exact question asked, sure. But for anyone who sleeps in the same room as their Windows 10 desktop or charging laptop ...

Comment: @NickWestgate You must be a really light sleeper if you're awoken by Windows Update. You could just do a proper shutdown instead of sleeping. Windows 10 does a hybrid shutdown which makes it boot almost instantly (assuming you have an SSD), so not much point leaving it on overnight unless you're running something important.

Comment: @Dan: Thanks, but I prefer not to rearrange my life arround MS's incompetence. ; - )

Comment: @Dan: I'm away from my computer for a few days at a time and I sometimes need to access my computer remotely. If it's in sleep state I can send a WOL packet, to wake it and put it to sleep when finished. However, I don't want it waking up by Windows Update and wasting power for days.

Comment: Btw make sure you check this setting after every single update Microsoft rolls out. With Win 10 things tend to reset to their default on their own after an update (including privacy settings mind you...)

Answer (score 86):

On WIN 10 there is an option in Local Group Policy Editor to set up it easily:

1. **Search:** `Local Group Policy Editor` (you can launch `gpedit.msc`)
2. **Navigate to:** `Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Windows Update`
3. **Double click on:** `Enabling Windows Update Power Management to automatically wake up the system to install scheduled updates` and set it to "Disabled".

Figure for Local Group Policy Editor setting:

[image]

Comment: IMO this is the correct solution. To disable wake timers completely is not always desired.

Comment: +1, but I don't want it to wake up (at night) for any reason! There is a new setting for Allow wake timers: Important wake timers only. No idea what it does. Hopefully MS themselves will wake up and allow us to specify the time range during which wakes are allowed. Oh, and Windows 10 Home users don't have gpedit but apparently [can use a registry hack](http://superuser.com/questions/357033/windows-update-waking-machine-from-hibernation/357124#357124).

Comment: I've disabled the policy, but the windows task was still registered (checked with "powercfg –waketimers"). Had to go and manually disable the windows task as pointed out in https://superuser.com/a/958264/267379 to get it working. Hopefully the combination of two will work :D

Comment: I cannot confirm that this policy works. I had already set this policy to disabled since weeks, and yesterday evening the task "UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" woke the computer up from sleep.

Comment: @ThorstenAlbrecht Same here.  I'm running 64-bit Windows 10 Pro v1703 (Build 15063.540) and the `UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot`  scheduled task resumed from hibernation this morning even though I have this policy set to `Disabled`.  Actually, I'm surprised my Local Group Policy settings didn't get blown away by the Creator's Update like most everything else did.  At the very least I'll try unsetting and resetting this policy and see if that has any effect.

Comment: @ BACON: I can recommend a method found at winaero.com to prevent the system to create a task called "reboot". Disabling this task is not enough because it could be recreated after an update: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-permanently-stop-windows-10-reboots-after-installing-updates/ Now my PC has no chance to wake up anymore!

Comment: That didn't work, computer woke up at 1am again, staying on all night long. Why did Microsoft think it was a good idea to do this??

Comment: Is this still possible? I don't see gpedit anywhere in Windows 10 now.

Comment: @Behacad gpedit is only available on Pro or higher editions.

Answer (score 44):

After upgrading to Windows 10, the computer in my bedroom kept waking me up at 3AM.  Disabling `Wake the computer` on the `Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot` scheduled task didn't help.  Windows turns the flag back on periodically.   Even disabling "Disable wake timers" in Power Options didn't help.  The UpdateOrchestrator kept orchestrating midnight alarms.

As a solution I've added a powershell script that removes wake settings every hour.

1. To allow running powershell scripts: run powershell as administrator, and run:

   `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`
2. Create a file called "disable_wakejobs.ps1" that contains one line of code:

   `Get-ScheduledTask | ? {$_.Settings.WakeToRun -eq $true -and $_.State -ne "Disabled"} | % {$_.Settings.WakeToRun = $false; Set-ScheduledTask $_}`
3. Open Task Scheduler and create a scheduled task.
4. In the "General" tab, set the user account to "SYSTEM" user (or you'll have to update a saved password every time you change your own password.)
5. In the "Triggers" tab, create a trigger that runs the job daily and repeat every hour.
6. In the "Actions" tab, create an action to "Start a program", with "Program/script" set to "PowerShell.exe", and arguments `-Command "c:\tools\disable_wakejobs.ps1"` (change the path to where you stored `disable_wakejobs.ps1` in step 2.)

The PowerShell commands come from [this blog post by Reidar Johansen](http://johansenreidar.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/powershell-things-to-check-if-computer.html).

Comment: I get an error running this: Set-ScheduledTask : The parameter is incorrect.
At C:\Users\Filip\scripts\disable_wakejobs.ps1:1 char:123
+ ... Disabled"} | % {$_.Settings.WakeToRun = $false; Set-ScheduledTask $_}
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Set-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,Set-ScheduledTask

Comment: None of the other solutions worked for me so I'm hoping this does the trick! Hacky, but whatever I can do to not have my PC turn on in the middle of the night, I'll do.

Comment: How crazy is that? You cannot even rely on the settings anymore and they got resetted. Is microsoft out of their mind? It's totaly unreliable.

Comment: I see no way to  set the user account to "SYSTEM" user in step 4.

Comment: @Castaa- bit later, but you change it by selecting Change User or Group, and then typing in `System` and then press `check name`. End result should look like this: http://puu.sh/mOIX4/58082e816e.png

Comment: This is great, though running hourly might be unnecessary. I've set this trigger on sleep and it seems to work perfectly.
On Event - Log: System, Source Kernel-Power, Evernt ID: 42

Comment: Seems like the task is just running for ages, doesn't just finish after executing it. I also enabled Task history for all tasks and realized that *Created Task Process* entry has this comment: `Task Scheduler launch task "\Disable WakeUp Timers" , instance "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"  with process ID 8760.`? WTF? Why is it running notepad and not executing the `sp1` script I have provided? In *Actions* for this task I have `Start a programm` with value `C:\disable_wake_jobs.ps1`.

Comment: +1 Because I already applied the solutions suggested by _xxxbece_ and _Nick Westgate_, and those didn't work in my case. This script is brilliant. It acts as a "firewall" for sneaky apps and can be extended to allow some to wake your pc.

Answer (score 5):

This should solve your problem:

1. Search `Task Scheduler`
2. Navigate to `Task Scheduler Library\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot`
   **Note:** `Reboot` is just a file, but you need to go inside all those folders
3. Right Click **Properties** then click **Conditions**
4. Uncheck `Wake the computer to run this task`

Comment: I have change that, hopefully it will not run again.

Comment: This is not the solution; Windows will re-enable the checkbox again next time :-(

Comment: I did this, but Windows turned the flag back on. Windows even ignores the "Disable wake timers" setting. Here's a [blog post](http://johansenreidar.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/powershell-things-to-check-if-computer.html) that shows how to uncheck the "Wake the computer" from a scheduled task.

Comment: Yes, the checkbox is enabled again...

Comment: Not only that WIndows resets this option, it even fails to enter it as a reason so that the user knows why the computer rebooted: When I ask powercfg for the reason, it says "unknown" :( this is bad by design, and Microsoft should fix this ASAP, took me hours to actually find out what kept waking up my system.

Besides, the reboot was totally unnecessary, because I already did it right after the update, but Microsoft decided to reboot anyway :(

Comment: This 'destroyed' my laptop's battery, computer woke and overheated in the laptop bag. Lucky to get 30 minutes from my laptop where I used to get 2 hours. Thanks MS

Answer (score 5):

I am using Wake On LAN (WOL) feature on my computer so that I can wake up my computer remotely if I need to access it while I am away.. in order for WOL to work is that I have to allow my network card to wake the computer when I send the WOL magic packet.

This is somehow causing my computer to wake up randomly for no apparent reason. To know whether this is causing your computer to wake up randomly, type this command in the command prompt:

```
powercfg -lastwake
```

[image]

If you see something about your network card (as of mine Realtek PCIe).. then you need to go to your network card properties setting and make sure the `Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer` check box is checked (mine wasn't):

[image]

Then pray to your God...

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me :D

Comment: That's a good solution to a different question. The question identifies  "TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" in Windows 10 as the cause. WOL is tricky to get set up properly though, so hopefully this helps others too.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into problem where UpdateOrchestrator re-enabled itself again. This ofcourse caused my computer to wake up from sleep mode by itself (seriously snap you microsoft for also waking me up in the middle of the night). Found some info on reddit that seems to solve it.

Open powershell:

- run: Get-ScheduledTask | where {$_.settings.waketorun}

Open cmd:

- Run SCHTASKS /Change /TN
  "Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" /DISABLE
- Run icacls "%WINDIR%\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" /inheritance:r /deny "Everyone:F" /deny "SYSTEM:F" /deny "Local Service:F" /deny "Administrators:F".

This will prevent the task from being enabled again. This assumes you're running an English version of Windows - translate the user names as necessary or find the SIDs, if required.

Original post on reddit.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/48rg7x/is_there_any_way_to_stop_updateorchestrator_for/

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be the system maintenance task running. If so, you might try disabling system maintenance.

WIN+R control
search for "maintenance" in the search box, select "Change Automatic Maintenance settings".

Clear the "allow scheduled maintenance to wake up my computer at the scheduled time".

See if that helps remove the issue. It's going to be a lot more reliable than some of the other mechanisms proposed.

Comment: I have this checkbox unchecked. (So it won't help in my case.)

Answer (score 1):

Applying Andomar's solution, I also got the error:

- Set-ScheduledTask : The parameter is incorrect. At C:\Users\Filip\scripts\disable_wakejobs.ps1:1 char:123 + ... Disabled"} | % {$*.Settings.WakeToRun = $false; Set-ScheduledTask $*} + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Set-ScheduledTask], CimException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,Set-ScheduledTask

In my case this was due to a task which cannot be edited (AUSessionConnect within WindowsUpdate to be precise). So I edit the responsible task directly (Reboot within UpdateOrchestrator). The corresponding disable_wakejobs.ps1 file looks like this (for how to use that file, check out Andomar's answer):

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Reboot" | % {$_.Settings.WakeToRun = $false; Set-ScheduledTask $_}
```

To test the script manually ensure you run it from an elevated PowerShell instance (Run as Admin).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, you can configure the auto update policy instead as a workaround:

1. Open Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc)
2. Go to: Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Windows Update
3. Modify "Configure Automatic Updates", you can enable it and set it as "2 - Notify for download and notify for install" or "3 - Auto download and notify for install"

This way the system doesn't even have the chance to start installing updates, which results in waking up and rebooting in most cases. In addition, you have the control over when to update.

Answer (score 0):

windows 10 has two things you can diable for wake timers

when you go into advanced power setting I found under wake timers you will see disable wake timers then under that you will see an important wake timer, disable that one too.

Comment: It seems to me that it depends whether the PC can have battery or not. I have updated the Nick answer.