# How to prevent windows updating the UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot task?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, hibernate, scheduled-tasks

What process is creating the Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot task?

A solution to prevent laptop to start [suggested here](https://superuser.com/questions/958109/how-to-prevent-windows-10-waking-from-sleep-when-traveling-in-bag/959983#959983) was to create an scheduled task that uncheck "wake to run" task option.

Is it possible to prevent (re)creation of that task?

**CLARIFICATION:**
How to do it in Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 3):

I found this fix on another site.  Group Policy has an entry for:

> Enabling Windows Update Power Management to automatically wake up the system to install scheduled updates

It is under "Computer Configuration -> Windows Components -> Windows Update".

I set it to "Disabled".
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I need it for Windows 10 Home. (I have updated the answer.)