# Windows 10 restarts when trying to hibernate

Tags: windows, windows-10, hibernate

I'm having some issues with Windows 10. I have activated Hibernate button from Energy options because it is not enabled by default. Now, the problem is when I try to hibernate my PC, the systems restarts and never gets Hibernated.

I have disabled Windows Update because in windows 7 when there is any new update ready to install, system never hibernates until it has been installed.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

EDIT:

I have updated nvidia graphics drivers and the issue remains.

My hardware configuration : 
DELL XPSL702X
Intel i7-2670QM 2.20GHz
Nvidia 555GTM
WINDOWS 10 HOME x64

EVENT LOG:

```
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:58:32 rt640x64    1   Ninguno
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:49:26 Search  3036    Recopilador
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:49:26 Search  3036    Recopilador
Error   27/08/2015 12:45:21 Application Error   1000    (100)
Error   27/08/2015 12:43:45 DistributedCOM  10016   Ninguno
Error   27/08/2015 12:43:20 Service Control Manager 7011    Ninguno
Error   27/08/2015 12:40:16 Service Control Manager 7009    Ninguno
Error   27/08/2015 12:40:16 Service Control Manager 7000    Ninguno
Error   27/08/2015 12:39:58 DeviceSetupManager  131 Ninguno
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:46 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:45 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Error   27/08/2015 12:39:43 Service Control Manager 7001    Ninguno
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:43 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:41 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:41 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:41 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:41 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:41 DeviceSetupManager  200 Ninguno
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:41 DeviceSetupManager  202 Ninguno
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:41 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:41 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:41 TaskScheduler   414 Error de configuración de la tarea
Advertencia 27/08/2015 12:39:38 DeviceSetupManager  201 Ninguno
```

Comment: Is there anything in the Event Log? What kind of hardware (Brand/Type) is that OS running on?

Comment: Can you check your Device Manager for any devices which have issues or have yet to be installed with appropriate drivers?

Answer (score 15):

I was looking for solutions for the same issue and here's what helped me:

[How to prevent Windows 10 waking from sleep when traveling in bag?](https://superuser.com/questions/958109/how-to-prevent-windows-10-waking-from-sleep-when-traveling-in-bag)

> Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Power Options
>
> for the active (selected) plan, click "Edit Plan Settings" link
>
> click "Change advanced power settings" link
>
> Go to "Sleep -> Allow wake timers" and change the setting to Disable.

Thanks go to [Nick Westgate](https://superuser.com/users/45942/nick-westgate).

Additionally, [from another forum thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/08c44326-01ef-4287-8d25-7e3b475a1570/pc-restarts-after-hibernating?forum=w7itproperf):

> Go to device manager and pull up properties on the mouse, keyboard, and network cards.  In each go to the Power Management tab and uncheck the "Allow to wake computer" box.

After following the steps, my PC was able to hibernate without rebooting. But I'll try also the other steps mentioned in that thread to avoid other cases of unexpected wake-up (e.g. disabling wake condition for UpdateOrchestrator scheduled task).

Comment: What if there is no "Power Management tab" in the device manager's device properties?

Comment: Then, most probably, the device does not support power management features and does not cause unwanted waking up.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an issue with your graphics driver,mostly on external graphics.

Try and download the latest graphic driver update for your graphics card.

I had the same problem with my windows 8.1,turned out a driver problem.

Answer (score 1):

Might be because of hybrid sleep.
Try to turn it off:

`Win`+`R` powercfg.cpl `Enter`

Change plan settings

Change advanced power settings

Sleep -> Allow Hybrid Sleep -> (set it to off)

Answer (score 0):

In case just various setting don't solve anything:

Update your BIOS.

Update your video card drivers (and even firmware).

Most of the time I encountered something similar it was either the nv video driver at fault or the lack of a recent BIOS version.

Answer (score -1):

Turning off TPM Security setting in my DELL Latitude BIOS caused my laptop to restart after clicking 'Hibernate' button. Turning TPM On back solved this issue.