# Windows 10 reboots immediately after hibernate

Tags: windows, hibernate, event-viewer

Since a few days I can't put my Windows 10 PC into hibernation anymore.

When I shutdown / hibernate the PC, it immediately restarts a few seconds later, staying at the login screen forever until I unplug the power.

First I thought that Windows 10 is trying (and fails) to install updates, but I alreadyy completely disabled update installation and the PC is up to date.

My Question: **How can I find out the reason for all these reboots?**

Looking at the Windows event viewer, I can see the Event-ID 107, stating *"The system has been reactivated from energy saving mode"* (translated from german).

Here's the full event information:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power"/>
    <EventID>107</EventID>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>102</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000400000000444</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-03-11T23:31:47.263015700Z"/>
    <EventRecordID>6181</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation/>
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="5240"/>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>**my pc name**</Computer>
    <Security/>
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="TargetState">5</Data>
    <Data Name="EffectiveState">5</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeFromState">5</Data>
    <Data Name="ProgrammedWakeTimeAc">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="ProgrammedWakeTimeDc">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeRequesterTypeAc">0</Data>
    <Data Name="WakeRequesterTypeDc">0</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Note: I am not interested in a list of settings which might resolve the issue (this can be found here: [Windows 10 restarts when trying to hibernate](https://superuser.com/questions/963016/windows-10-restarts-when-trying-to-hibernate)). I'm rather interested if Windows offers the possibility to identify the reason directly.

Something like a table that says *"Event 107 is a reboot triggered by the mouse input device if the keywords have the value xyz"*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 restarts when trying to hibernate](//superuser.com/q/963016)

Comment: @DavidPostill This is not a duplicate. I'm interested in finding out the process of how to identify the exact problem. The answers of the other question just mention a list of settings that can all be deactived which might resolve the issue.

Comment: If you try them one by one then you can find out which one (if any) is the cause of your problem.

Comment: @DavidPostill Only if one of them IS actually the problem. This is not a generic solution on how to find out what triggered a specific event.

Comment: For this kind of problem **there is no generic solution**.

Comment: @DavidPostill It would be a shame if Windows doesn't log such information somewhere deep in its system, but forces us to use trial & error instead. I wouldn't be suprised though.

Comment: The event log is the only place where this kind of windows logging happens, unless you are running debug versions of the errant software ...

Answer (score 2):

Since you appear to be asking for means to investigate rather than a laundry-list of settings which might effect a cure, then from command prompt issue:

```
POWERCFG /LASTWAKE
```

According to the online help for POWERCFG:

```
/LASTWAKE          Reports information about what woke the system from the 
                   last sleep transition.
```

Lots of other useful things you can investigate or set using POWERCFG:

```
POWERCFG /?
```

Will result in a helpful list.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem on my computer with auto-restart after hibernation shutdown.  Previously my computer was hibernating normally, and not automatically restarting.

I tried deleting some programs, that were displaying error message in event viewer under Administrative Services in Control Panel.  I also set selective start-up under System Configuration from Control Panel.

This appears to have enabled hibernation to work normally, and not automatically restart the computer.

The next step would be to add the programs that load upon startup one by one until the offending program is found.  A bit tedious, but should identify the program causing the restart from hibernation.

Hope this will assist in finding the problem.