# Why does my Windows 10 Laptop fail to hibernate sometimes?

Tags: hibernate

After I click 'Hibernate', my laptop does hibernate, but only sometimes. Other times, the screen immediately fades black. But then the power button stays illuminated, and 10 s later (after I clicked 'Hibernate') the screen reappears, with everything before still opened.In both cases, my laptop had the same 3 USB devices plugged.

[Disabling Wake Timers](https://superuser.com/a/1010466/269574) and [seeking the Wake Source](https://superuser.com/a/113868/269574) didn't help:

[image]

#### Update on 28 July 2018

Performing the steps in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1343240/269574), didn't help. See [this](https://superuser.com/q/1345737/269574) for my most updated energy-report.html.

Answer (score 7):

Bingo!!! I seem to have successfully troubleshooted and resolved a similar issue with the help of this reddit post: [Has anyone else noticed that their computer no longer goes to sleep automatically after updating to Windows 10?](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/3hda3b/has_anyone_else_noticed_that_their_computer_no/)

**Steps to troubleshoot:**

1. **Using the Power Efficiency Diagnostics Report**

As already mentioned by Harrymc, you can use the `powercfg -energy` command to get a report of its power-use diagnostics. The result may indicate errors, warnings or other useful information and is stored here: `C:\Windows\System32\energy-report.html`

For example my summary report was:

```
Energy efficiency problems were found.

9 Errors
24 Warnings
43 Informational

See C:\WINDOWS\system32\energy-report.html for more details.
```

and the more detailed:

```
Analysis Results

Errors


System Availability Requests:System Required Request
The program has made a request to prevent the system from automatically entering sleep.
Requesting Process
\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Connectify\Connectifyd.exe
System Availability Requests:Execution Required Request
The program has made a request for execution required.
Requesting Process
\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Users\ratxavier\PortableApps\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe
System Availability Requests:System Required Request
The device or driver has made a request to prevent the system from automatically entering sleep.
Requesting Driver Instance
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_8086&DEV_2807&SUBSYS_80860101&REV_1000\4&353e01dc&0&0001
Requesting Driver Device
Intel(R) Display Audio
System Availability Requests:System Required Request
A kernel component has made a request to prevent the system from automatically entering sleep.
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Selective Suspend
This device did not enter the USB Selective Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented when this USB device is not in the Selective Suspend state. Note that this issue will not prevent the system from sleeping.
Device Name
USB Input Device
Host Controller ID
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9C31
Host Controller Location
PCI bus 0, device 20, function 0
Device ID
USB\VID_045E&PID_0797
Port Path
1
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Selective Suspend
This device did not enter the USB Selective Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented when this USB device is not in the Selective Suspend state. Note that this issue will not prevent the system from sleeping.
Device Name
USB Composite Device
Host Controller ID
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9C26
Host Controller Location
PCI bus 0, device 29, function 0
Device ID
USB\VID_19D2&PID_FFF1
Port Path
1,2
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Selective Suspend
This device did not enter the USB Selective Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented when this USB device is not in the Selective Suspend state. Note that this issue will not prevent the system from sleeping.
Device Name
USB Root Hub
Host Controller ID
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9C26
Host Controller Location
PCI bus 0, device 29, function 0
Device ID
USB\VID_8086&PID_9C26
Port Path

CPU Utilisation:Processor utilisation is high
The average processor utilisation during the trace was high. The system will consume less power when the average processor utilisation is very low. Review processor utilisation for individual processes to determine which applications and services contribute the most to total processor utilisation.
Average Utilisation (%)
21.73
Platform Power Management Capabilities:PCI Express Active-State Power Management (ASPM) Disabled
PCI Express Active-State Power Management (ASPM) has been disabled due to a known incompatibility with the hardware in this computer.
Warnings
Platform Timer Resolution:Platform Timer Resolution
The default platform timer resolution is 15.6 ms (15625000 ns) and should be used whenever the system is idle. If the timer resolution is increased, processor power management technologies may not be effective. The timer resolution may be increased due to multimedia playback or graphical animations.
Current Timer Resolution (100 ns units)
5003
Maximum Timer Period (100 ns units)
156250
Platform Timer Resolution:Outstanding Timer Request
A program or service has requested a timer resolution smaller than the platform maximum timer resolution.
Requested Period
10000
Requesting Process ID
7800
Requesting Process Path
\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Users\ratxavier\PortableApps\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe
Platform Timer Resolution:Outstanding Timer Request
A program or service has requested a timer resolution smaller than the platform maximum timer resolution.
Requested Period
10000
Requesting Process ID
7908
Requesting Process Path
\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Users\ratxavier\PortableApps\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe
```

2. **Using powercfg -requests**

Typing `powercfg -requests` into a command prompt (might have to be elevated). 
 should tell you what programming is keeping **your PC awake**. For my report I got:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg -requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
[PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Connectify\Connectifyd.exe
[DRIVER] Intel(R) Display Audio (HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_8086&DEV_2807&SUBSYS_80860101&REV_1000\4&353e01dc&0&0001)
An audio stream is currently in use.
[DRIVER] Legacy Kernel Caller

AWAYMODE:
None.

EXECUTION:
[PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Users\ratxavier\PortableApps\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe
Playing audio

PERFBOOST:
None.

ACTIVELOCKSCREEN:
None.
```

---

**Resolutions**

- Overriding the programming keeping windows awake. Using the command

  `powercfg -REQUESTSOVERRIDE`

  tells windows to ignore whatever is keeping it awake and go to sleep.

For instance according to my report I had to override the `Kernel Driver` and `Connectifyd` process.

**Note!** *You do not have to necessarily override it, because it the given driver might be keeping the PC awake because its in use, a good example is the Intel Audio Driver above, after stopping the audio its no longer active.*

My culprit was the process - `Connectifyd`.

Nevertheless to override type this commands accordingly:

```
powercfg -REQUESTSOVERRIDE DRIVER "The Name of Your Device" SYSTEM

powercfg -REQUESTSOVERRIDE PROCESS "The name of Process" SYSTEM
```

e.g

```
powercfg -REQUESTSOVERRIDE PROCESS "\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Connectify\Connectifyd.exe" SYSTEM
```

Credits: Simplifyze (Reddit);[Has anyone else noticed that their computer no longer goes to sleep automatically after updating to Windows 10?](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/3hda3b/has_anyone_else_noticed_that_their_computer_no/)

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the issue may be due to USB Root Hub being allowed to wake your PC. Would you try unchecking the box to see if it works? Steps below:

1. Search for "Device Manager" in your start bar.
2. Once Device Manager is open, near the bottom, expand "Universal Serial Bus Controllers"
3. Locate "USB Root HUB". There will likely be more than one. Do steps 4-6 on each USB Root Hub.
4. Right click USB Root Hub > Properties > Power Management.
5. Uncheck "Allow this device to wake the computer"
6. OK - Test solution. If the solution doesn't work, try a reboot before rechecking the boxes.

Let us know if this works!

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't. Please see my edited post.

Comment: Have the same issue, and have all options unchecked for root hubs, but it still persists an other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

An examination of your `powercfg -energy` report did not show any anomaly.
Your system is reported as hibernation-capable (S4) and there are no
obvious problematic devices (although it would have been better to make it
while you were not using the computer or playing music).

Below is some advice which might help.

1. [Turn Off and Disable Hybrid Sleep](https://techjourney.net/turn-off-and-disable-hybrid-sleep-in-windows-10-8-1-8-7-vista/)

[image]

2. Prevent devices from waking your computer,
   and especially the network adapter, in Device Manager.
   You may list all these devices by running `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed`.
3. Check Windows for corruption via [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).
   If problems are found and corrected, do not assume that they were fully fixed.