# Sleep mode closing all my apps,when waking up the machine

Tags: windows-10, sleep, wake-up

I noticed yesterday , that when I resume from the sleep state, all my opened apps are gone. They don't stay in the RAM, so when the machine wakes up, I have to reopen everything AGAIN. When I wake up my laptop, it takes a lot more time, like it was powered off.

I tried the following:

- uninstalled everything
- I installed recently updated all the drivers
- I reinstalled Windows again
- erased my C: partition.

I had no sleep problems before yesterday.

So I am thinking this may be a Windows problem or a hardware problem.

I have an Asus S551LN, with Intel  i5-4210U CPU, NVIDIA GeForce 840M, 8gb RAM. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **`it takes a lot more`** what?

Comment: I posted this a while ago but if anyone still has this problem, I partially fixed it by disabling the Update Orchestrate and Fast startup. Basically follow and apply all the fixes from here : [https://superuser.com/questions/958109/how-to-prevent-windows-10-waking-from-sleep-when-traveling-in-bag]

Answer (score 0):

Are there any related error or warning messages recorded in the Event Viewer(Windows Logs\Application, System)?

"Also , when i wake up my laptop, it takes a lot more, like it was shutted down, not put to sleep."
Did you see the machine logo when you wake up the machine?
If you see the machine logo, the machine was not going to sleep before. It was shut down.

We could open a command line and run "powercfg /energy" to get an energy report to get more information to troubleshoot this issue. Pay attention to the errors and the warnings.

I hope the built-in troubleshoot tool will be useful.
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Troubleshooting\All Categories\Power

" a hardware problem"
Since the present working status is saved in the RAM when we get into sleep mode, please check your RAM stick(Try to clear it).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know you have corrected it or not because it happened long time ago, but I've just got exactly the same issue with you when I update windows to 1709 version.
After 1 week trying all of thing, including replace my HDD by SSD. It still happen.
I finally update my BIOS as the last change. Like a magic, It work, my laptop return to the best status.
Let try my solution if you have no idea about how to fix it :D