# How to prevent Windows 10 from automatically waking up?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

My Windows 10 PC randomly wakes up from both sleep and hibernation even though I did not interact with it.

I made sure that no devices are primed for waking up my pc:

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
```

and I could disable that easily via device manager and the devices power settings--the issue persisted.

Checking the reason for the last wake, I see:

```
C:\Users\Philipp>powercfg -lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Wake Timer
    Owner: [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SystemEventsBroker)
    Owner Supplied Reason: Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Universal Orchestrator Start' scheduled task that requested waking the computer.
```

How can I disable / disallow UpdateOrchestrator\Universal Orchestrator Start to wake my PC from sleep? I only want my PC to wake up when its power button is pressed.

If I have disabled it, how would I check if this setting was still disabled?

---

I found a setting  in the "Security and Maintenance" > "Automatic Maintenance Windows" where it was enabled to: `Allow scheduled maintenance to wake up my computer at the scheduled time`. Was that the offending setting? (I doubt it as the wake event happens at random times and the setting implies it will only run at 2am).

---

Listing active wake-timers through an elavated cmd terminal (Win + X > Windows Power Shell (admin) and running:

```
powercfg -waketimers
```

still lists an entry:

```
Timer set by [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SystemEventsBroker) expires at 20:54:15 on 05.03.2020.
  Reason: Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Backup Scan' scheduled task that requested waking the computer.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Might be duplicated: https://superuser.com/questions/958109/how-to-prevent-windows-10-waking-from-sleep-when-traveling-in-bag?rq=1