# Windows 10 laptop no longer hibernating when turning back on after transporting

Tags: windows-10, laptop, crash, hibernate, diagnostic

My HP ProBook 430 *(SSD-only, 8GB RAM)* is running Win10 v1903 [b10.0.18362.900], and when I turn it back on after hibernation, it's no longer hibernating, with all open windows gone.

- This occurs sporadically when transporting the laptop, which is within a pouch *(thin foam between screen and keyboard)*, and I'm fairly certain it's never happened when not transporting the laptop

How can I determine the cause of my laptop losing hibernation?

- **`powercfg -devicequery s4_supported`**

  ```
  Broadcom BCM943228HMB 802.11abgn 2x2 Wi-Fi Adapter
  Motherboard resources
  Motherboard resources (001)
  USB Root Hub
  Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Embedded Controller
  System CMOS/real time clock
  Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery
  Root Print Queue
  ACPI Thermal Zone
  Programmable interrupt controller
  Volume Manager
  Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
  Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
  High Definition Audio Controller
  Fax
  WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
  Pci Bus
  PCI standard host CPU bridge
  Microsoft Basic Display Driver
  Realtek High Definition Audio
  HP Wireless Button Driver
  ACPI Sleep Button
  Extended IO Bus

  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz
  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz (001)
  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz (002)
  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz (003)

  VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
  Direct memory access controller
  Microsoft Windows Management Interface for ACPI
  Intel(R) 8 Series LPC Controller (Premium SKU) - 9C43
  Standard PS/2 Keyboard
  WAN Miniport (PPTP)
  Broadcom Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter
  Microsoft Hyper-V Virtualization Infrastructure Driver
  High precision event timer
  WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
  Composite Bus Enumerator
  Microsoft Virtual Drive Enumerator
  Microsoft AC Adapter
  Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller
  USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)
  Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
  ACPI Lid
  ACPI Thermal Zone (001)
  UMBus Root Bus Enumerator
  Charge Arbitration Driver
  ACPI Thermal Zone (002)
  ACPI x64-based PC
  HID-compliant wireless radio controls
  WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
  WAN Miniport (IP)
  Legacy device
  Trusted Platform Module 1.2
  Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  マイク (Realtek High Definition Audio)
  Microsoft ACPI-Compliant System
  Microsoft Basic Render Driver
  OneNote for Windows 10
  WAN Miniport (SSTP)
  ACPI Fixed Feature Button
  System timer

  Intel(R) 8 Series PCI Express Root Port #4 - 9C16
  Generic USB Hub
  Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
  Microsoft Print to PDF

  Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)
  Standard SATA AHCI Controller
  Intel(R) Smart Connect Technology Device
  ACPI Thermal Zone (003)
  Synaptics PS/2 Port TouchPad
  Realtek PCIE CardReader
  Generic PnP Monitor

  Intel(R) 8 Series PCI Express Root Port #3 - 9C14
  ACPI Thermal Zone (004)
  Intel(R) 8 Series USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 - 9C26
  NDIS Virtual Network Adapter Enumerator
  Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
  SAMSUNG MZ7PD256HAFV-000H7
  ACPI Thermal Zone (005)

  Intel(R) 8 Series PCI Express Root Port #2 - 9C12
  Intel(R) 8 Series Thermal - 9C24
  Microsoft System Management BIOS Driver
  Motherboard resources (002)
  Microsoft XPS Document Writer
  Speakers/Headphones (Realtek High Definition Audio)
  Plug and Play Software Device Enumerator
  Remote Desktop Device Redirector Bus
  WAN Miniport (IPv6)

  Intel(R) 8 Series PCI Express Root Port #1 - 9C10
  HP Mobile Data Protection Sensor
  WAN Miniport (L2TP)
  ```
- **`powercfg -waketimers`:**

  ```
  Timer set by [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SystemEventsBroker) expires at 12:26:30 AM on 16/06/2020.
    Reason: Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Universal Orchestrator Start' scheduled task that requested waking the computer.

  Timer set by [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe expires at 12:26:30 AM on 16/06/2020.
  ```
- **`powercfg /availablesleepstates`:**

  ```
  The following sleep states are available on this system:
      Standby (S3)
      Hibernate
      Hybrid Sleep
      Fast Startup

  The following sleep states are not available on this system:
      Standby (S1)
          The system firmware does not support this standby state.

      Standby (S2)
          The system firmware does not support this standby state.

      Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
          The system firmware does not support this standby state.
  ```

Comment: You might want to try __POWERCFG -DEVICEQUERY S4_supported__ to make sure your Solid State Drive (SSD) is supported.

Comment: @vssher: I'll add its output to my question. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Another Useful command is __powercfg /availablesleepstates__ _SEE IF_ 
Hybrid sleep is enabled, If so, this may be causing issues with the Hibernate function. There are also other things which may be keeping it from hibernating, If the above does not work you might want to visit this page, if you have not alread, https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-hibernation-your-pc-running-windows-10

Comment: @vssher: It says it's available but doesn't say it's enabled. It definitely hibernates. I often press a few keys after the lights and fan go off just to make sure. It also hasn't restarted when I've hibernated in the past five days since the last trip I took it on. Adding output of your command to my question.

Comment: Sometimes, your hiberfil.sys file can become corrupted or fragmented, and it has to be deleted and created anew. Disable hibernation from the command line, enable it again, and if you're not too stingy on free space, enter a "powercfg hibernate size 100" command that will set the size of the hiberfil.sys file at 100% of your installed RAM, IOW 8GB in your case. That way, Windows won't have to compress the content of the RAM before copying it to disk, and your PC will hibernate more quickly, and resume faster too.

Comment: @Didier: Thanks for those tips. I am actually shopping for both a second SSD and a RAM upgrade at the moment so I'll give your suggestion a try when I get them.

Comment: Could be a myriad of things, so troubleshooting should be the simplest reasons to the more complex ones _(I'd recommend @Didier's suggestion first - can also be achieved by booting to WinRE and manually deleting `hiberfil.sys`)_: **(1)** Scheduled task is waking it from Hibernate _(because it's not shutting back down/re-entering hibernate, the battery is dying or a shutdown is being executed by the OS)_; **(2)** Loose battery connection or battery is failing - piggy-backing on #1 _(laptop batteries only have a 300 - 500 charge-cycle lifetime when charged to 100%)_

Comment: @JW0914: Battery definitely doesn't seem like a new one anymore but also does not feel like close to failing any time soon. I've had laptop batteries get to that point before so think I'd recognize it.

Comment: @hippietrail Does this occur if no foam is inserted between the screen and keyboard? _(I'm assuming this is a laptop not a tablet, and they're engineered so the keys won't touch the screen with the laptop closed)_

Comment: Related question: [How to prevent Windows 10 waking from sleep when traveling in bag?](https://superuser.com/questions/958109/how-to-prevent-windows-10-waking-from-sleep-when-traveling-in-bag)

Comment: @JW0914: I've actually started to wonder that. I asked, perhaps on this site, where to get the right kind of foam with no good answer. I made a piece from some I found that's a tiny bit thicker than what my old laptop came with. I cut it from what was probably the foam wrapping inside a big flatscreen TV. I might make a cutout where the power button is to be sure.

Comment: @hippietrail Another option could be to only place foam around the keyboard [keyboard cutout], leaving any keys uncovered, as you'd still get the same protection, just without potentially accidental button pushes.