# Can not turn off computer

Tags: bios, power-supply, compaq-desktop-computer

When i turn off computer stays off for few moments (no sounds and lights) and reboots.
I encountered power grid variation, maybe this caused problem.
Tried various bios options and cmos reset but for no awail.
It's HP Compaq DC7900 sff with Windows 7 and Lubuntu 21.10 in dual boot.

Comment: Look in BIOS (UEFI) for Wake on ... whatever. That may be the issue.

Comment: I think john is on to something, but I think it would not under be "wake on {lan|usb| etc.}" but rather "power loss" or "power on options" ( https://superuser.com/questions/1175450/disable-power-on-after-power-loss )

Comment: Look in the Event Viewer for interesting messages.